# How do i use regular expressions to ONLY identify consecutive 4-5 digit numbers within a pandas dataframe

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

The following code is set up with hard coded data frames that can be copied and pasted into a anaconda3 jupyter notebook and looked at in a table view. Copy and paste code up though line that starts 'df2=' and in the jupyter notebood, run the code and you will see output if you type df1.head(14) and then run. Then type df2.head(14) to see the second data frame. And then you can run the rest of the code until you have the merged dataframe.

I need help adjusting this code to make it only identify 4 to five digit dept_nbrs. So in other words, how can i use regular expressions to not match any number unless it is 4 or 5 consecutive digits long? I don't want to identify any dept number that is tied to a city which are all one, two or three digits long (but i cant just remove those numbers from the original data frame. Any help is much appreciated. The desired outcome would look like this:

```
    Department         TrueDeparment    num_col Dept_Nbr    Dept_Desc_HR
0   Merch - 1854       Empty            1854    1854 Community Relations
1   1925 - WH          empty            1925    1925     Human Resources
2   Montreal 10        empty                 
3   CMI-General Liability | 05-9362 empty 9632  9632               Legal
4   Market 466         empty                
5   7763               empty            7763    7763       Merchandising
6   Realty Supply Chain 44-9635 empty   9635    9635          Contractor
7   Merchandising (18-9087) empty       9087    9087            Security
8   07-7882 | Supply Chain empty        7882    7882             Produce
9   6101-09-01 00:00:00 empty           6101    6101          Recruiting
10  Supply Chain Engineering 9826 empty 9826    9826                 R&D
11  Dept. 93 - Fresh Meat 01-9245 empty 9245    9245         Real Estate
12  Health & Wellness WBU Reg 54 empty  
13  US09027            empty            9027    9027     Retail Services
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Department' : ['Merch - 1854', '1925 - WH','Montreal 10','CMI-General Liability | 05-9362', 'Market 466','7763','Realty Supply Chain  44-9635','Merchandising (18-9087)','07-7882 | Supply Chain','6101-09-01 00:00:00','Supply Chain Engineering 9826','Dept. 93 - Fresh Meat 01-9245','Health & Wellness WBU Reg 54','US09027'],'TrueDeparment' : ['Empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty']})   

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Dept_Nbr' : [1,5,7,9,10,18,44,54,93,466,1854,1925,6101,7763,7882,9027,9087,9245,9362,9635,9826], 'Dept_Desc_HR' : ['springfield','new orleans','san diego','new york','cleveland','orlando','san francisco','st louis','kansas city','detroit','Community Relations','Human Resources','Recruiting','Merchandising','Produce','Retail Services','Security','RealEstate','Legal','Contractor','R&D']})

line = 'Merch - 1854 '
match = re.search(r'[0-9]+', line)
if match is None:
    print(0)
else:
    print(int(match[0]))

def extract_number(field):
    match = re.search(r'[0-9]+', field)
    if match is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(match[0])

df1['num_col'] = df1[['Department']].apply(lambda row:extract_number(row['Department']),axis=1)

df1.merge(df2, left_on = ['num_col'], right_on = ['Dept_Nbr'])
```

Comment: *Consecutive* as in `1`, `2`, `3`, ... ? Otherwise just use `^\d{4,5}$`.

Comment: no consecutive meaning 4 or 5 digits in a row with no special characters or white space within these digits...i didn't word that very well. thank you so much for everyone's help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Department' : ['Merch - 1854', '1925 - WH','Montreal 10','CMI-General Liability | 05-9362', 'Market 466','7763','Realty Supply Chain  44-9635','Merchandising (18-9087)','07-7882 | Supply Chain','6101-09-01 00:00:00','Supply Chain Engineering 9826','Dept. 93 - Fresh Meat 01-9245','Health & Wellness WBU Reg 54','US09027'],'TrueDeparment' : ['Empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty']})   

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Dept_Nbr' : [1,5,7,9,10,18,44,54,93,466,1854,1925,6101,7763,7882,9027,9087,9245,9362,9635,9826], 'Dept_Desc_HR' : ['springfield','new orleans','san diego','new york','cleveland','orlando','san francisco','st louis','kansas city','detroit','Community Relations','Human Resources','Recruiting','Merchandising','Produce','Retail Services','Security','RealEstate','Legal','Contractor','R&D']})
```

As @Jan mentioned, you can use the regex \d{4,5} which matches a minimum of 4 and a maximum of 5 consecutive digit characters.

```
line = 'Merch - 1854 '
match = re.search(r'\d{4,5}', line)
if match is None:
    print(0)
else:
    print(int(match[0]))
```

Now pandas comes with builtin string operations and the one we want to use here is `pd.Series.str.extract`. We specify `expand` to be `False`, to only get the first match from each row. In case we don't specify this, pandas will return a DataFrame rather than a Series if there is more than one match in one of the lines. Finally notice we flanked our regex with a capturing group `()` which is what extract will write into the new Series. If there is no match, it will just return a `NaN` for those rows.

Edit: we change the dtype of the columns to floats (ints are upcasted to floats when the column contains `NaN` values), so the merge operation works.

```
df1['num_col'] = df1.Department.str.extract(r'(\d{4,5})', expand=False).astype(float)
df2.Dept_Nbr = df2.Dept_Nbr.astype(float)

df1.merge(df2, left_on = ['num_col'], right_on = ['Dept_Nbr'])
```

Comment: I have made edits! Changing the type of the columns we are merging on works

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Are you copying and pasting all of the code from my answer? The error you are getting means your df1 has no column called 'Department'

Comment: i can use df1.head() and clearly see that I have a column called Department

Comment: What does `print(pd.__version__)` print? What about `print(df1.columns)`?

Comment: pandas version is 0.23.0

Comment: Index([], dtype='object')

Comment: I just put the code in a colaboratory notebook, and it runs perfectly fine (using version `0.22.0` however):
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1i71FR5DFPGp2uYMLauPEQNJUXzXUHAkq

Comment: `Index([], dtype='object')` means your DataFrame has no columns, so something is wrong with your df1. I am making a pandas 0.23.0 environment right now, testing this out.

Comment: Works just fine in `0.23.0`, you must have incorrectly copied part of the example.

Comment: ummm im not sure what happened my friend but it is working now. thank you so much and i apologize for taking more of your time

Comment: No problem (especially not when your username has such an awesome pulp fiction ref), probably just a copy error - please accept the answer then.

Comment: I don't see that - do you see that in the colaboratory notebook that I shared?
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1i71FR5DFPGp2uYMLauPEQNJUXzXUHAkq

Comment: no i don't.  I was actually running it on a dataframe that has over 10000 rows....i think since that department appears over 150 times in the Department column it, is listing every occurence. yeah it works perfectly on both. the example dataframe and the huge dataframe as far as i can tell. thank you so much

Comment: i did already....one thing weird happening though is that i see some dept numbers that are only 2 and 3 digits long...i have less than 15 reputation so the upvote is recorded but not change the publicly displayed score. the 2 and three digit ones are showing up because they have zeros preceding them...now i have to figure out how to fix that but it is progress

Comment: It's not yet accepted, here is how to accept an answer: `https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to only match numbers which have exactly 4 or 5 digits, you can update your regular expression to use the {} operator, which indicates a specific number of times you want to match.

```
match = re.search(r'[0-9]{4,5}', line)
```

Additionally, since you want to match any number, you can use the \d operator which looks for any digit

```
match = re.search(r'\d{4,5}', line)
```

Answer (score 1):

4-5 digits with no other digits around it:

`(?<!\d)\d{4,5}(?!\d)`

requires assertions.